# Can we operate multiple tabs at the same time with selenium in java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is this possible to operate two or more than two Chrome tabs at the same time?

I Want to operate two or more than two tabs with one Webdriver object.
Please answer me if you have answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: No.

You may have multiple tabs at the same time if you have multiple chromedrivers or firefox drivers.